# Android: Mediaplayer plays multiple times if I keep on pressing the back button and launch the app again

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-activity

When I play my song and press the back button to return to return to home, the music continues playing. When I launch the app again, the music plays twice. I think it's the onResume method because I commented out the method and the problem stopped. How do I get onResume work properly? I tried using if(backgroundMusic.isplaying()) inside the onResume, but the app crashes when I resume from another activity. What am I doing wrong?

```
//global mediaplayer
MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    loadBackgroundMusic();

}

private void loadBackgroundMusic() {

    //load mp3 into object and start it
    backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.backgrounmusic);
    backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
    backgroundMusic.start();

}
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            backgroundMusic.release();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            loadBackgroundMusic();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            backgroundMusic.release();
        }
```

Comment: Could you describe the behavior you want?

Comment: i want the activity to play music when i resume the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about the behavior you want. As I see it, it's one of two:

1. Music should be played only while my Activity is visible

   If this is the case, you should look closer on the documentation for the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). This will for example tell you that `onResume()` will also be called the first time the Activity is created.

   So the solution would be to start the music in `onResume()` and stop on `onPause()` or similar.
2. After starting my activity once, music should be played even if i return to home screen

   In this case you really want a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: My question is what do I put inside onResume() so that the music plays when I return from onPause(). Currently I called loadBackgroundMusic(), which loads the mp3 and plays it again. By doing this, the music plays twice whenever I press the back button to return to home and relaunch the app again.

Comment: @iamarnold remove `loadBackgroundMusic()` from `onCreate()` and add `backgroundMusic.stop()` before `backgroundMusic.release()` in `onPause()`.