# Android play sound of resource

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have kept in resources mp3 file, you need play it with the MediaPlayer

path in Resource `Resources/Drawable/beep.mp3`

i trying this code

```
var fileUri = Uri.Parse("android.resource://MyAppName/" + Resource.Drawable.beep);
_mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(Application.Context,fileUri);
```

but the path of the file is incorrect,
how to get the correct path to the resource mp3 file

Comment: mp3 file path is assets/beep.mp3 and use the following code AssetFileDescriptor afd = getBaseContext().getAssets().openFd("beep.mp3");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using MP3 from the "drawable" directory, which is wrong.

Use assets.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I actually store my MP3 files in Resources/Raw and use `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer` for short clips like beeps, etc. See [Soundpool or media player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629812/soundpool-or-media-player)

```c#
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyView);

    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.VolumeControlStream = Stream.Music;

    // Load the sound
    _soundPool = new SoundPool(10, Stream.Music, 0);
    _beepId = _soundPool.Load(this, Resource.Raw.beep, 1);
}

private void PlaySound(int soundId)
{
    var audioManager = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(AudioService);
    var actualVolume = (float)audioManager.GetStreamVolume(Stream.Music);
    var maxVolume = (float)audioManager.GetStreamMaxVolume(Stream.Music);
    var volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

    _soundPool.Play(soundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

You can then simply call `PlaySound(_beepId)` to play your sound.

Comment: What is `GetSystemService` a part of?

Comment: It's part of the `Context` class, or in this case from `Activity`.

Comment: What about AudioService? It claims to be a static constant on mine, but you're using it in a non-static context.

Comment: That's correct. `AudioService` is static string constant from `Context` class. But since `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, it also inherits this constant. And you can reference your own static members without the class qualifier. You could easily use `Context.AudioService` or even `Activity.AudioService` if it'll make it clearer, even if it is redundant. It's like using `this` to reference instance members. It's not required (except to disambiguate).